# AS3: Get result found in parentheses in Regex pattern w/o using replace

Tags: regex, flash, actionscript-3, string, replace

This is my current workaround:

```
var str = "testing123";
var pattern = /([a-z]*)([0-9]*)/g;
var args;
str.replace(pattern, function(){args = arguments; return arguments[0];});
trace(args);
```

Output:

```
testing123,testing,123
```

But it would like do it like this:

```
var str = "testing123";
var pattern = /([a-z]*)([0-9]*)/g;
str.match(pattern);
trace(arguments);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I think so, but you'll obviously need to assign your result to 'arguments'.

Comment: I don't want to get the match(es) (testing123), but rather an array [testing123, testing, 123]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "testing123";
var pattern = /([a-z]*)([0-9]*)/g;
var hits:Object = pattern.exec (str);
for( var i:String in hits ) {
trace( i + " "+ hits[i] );
}

//outputs
0 testing123
1 testing
2 123
input testing123
index 0
```